# Openlayers 3. OnClick on touch device not triggering perfectly

Tags: openlayers, point, android, events

I have the forEachFeatureAtPixel function and try to trigger an event on click on a point layer with a custom icon. However, the performance on touch devices is really bad. I need to click several times until it triggers the event (sometimes it doesn'tdo it at all..) . I also used the moveTolerence feature for the map, but still have the same issues. On mouse click on my desktop PC everything works like a charme. What am I missing to make the performance as smooth as on a desktop PC?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    }, {hitTolerance:10});
    var layer = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return layer;
    }, {hitTolerance: 15});
    if (feature) {
        if (layer === vectorLayerFB) {
            window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (layer === vectorLayerBlog) {
            window.location = 'www.example.com';
        }
    }
}); 
[...]
});
```

Comment: 1. which version to you use? v3.x.x? 
2. have you tried to increase `hitTolerance` value as 30 something?

Comment: My ol version is v3.11.2. And yes, I have tried with a higher hitTolerance (20 / 30 / 100). It is always out of 10 clicks only one or two are working. Using Samsung S9+ with chrome but had same issues with a S6 on chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hitTolerance` parameter is introduced with [version 3.20.0](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/v3.20.0.md).
So, it's not working with [version 3.11.2](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) because there's no `hitTolerance`.
Up-versioning to 3.20.0 will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Would you suggest me to upgrade to the latest stable version? (If yes, which is it at the moment, if you know?)

Comment: Since version 5.0, there's huge changes on import things. The last 4.x.x version would be better to use for you.